# Get prioritisation based on limits

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am using excel 2010.

I have the following input:

[image]

I would like to get for each channel the highest prioritized product.

I have a channel prioritization for each product. So `product 1` has the channel prioritization of:

1. Mailbox
2. Telephone
3. Website

Furthermore, I have for each products the active events by day. So for all product on `day 0` the highest active event is `product 1`.

I would like to get for each channel the currently highest prioritized product.

I was thinking of using `Index-Match`, however I am struggling to get the prioritization out of the table.

Any suggestions how to get this via a formula?

Comment: Not sure about a formula, but you could look at the Solver - setting the criteria & a calculation to find the maximum will be the trick.